# I'm posting form data with AJAX, but the form keeps submitting and refreshing the page anyway. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

So I'm making a very small, very simple chat application using mostly JQuery / AJAX.

Here is my HTML form.

```
<form class="chat_form" method="post" id="chat_form" autocomplete="off">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="chatMe" placeholder="Type here..." autocomplete="off">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.chat_form').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "runMe.cfm",
        type: "POST",
        data: $('.chat_form').serialize(),    
        success: function() {
            $('.chat_form input').val('');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

To my understanding, that's supposed to submit all the form information to my action page then clear the input - and it does. That part works fine. I'm getting my data.

***But whenever I submit the form, the entire page reloads as if it's ignoring a key part of my code.***

Any help on that part? Thanks.

Comment: In addition to the answers below, your code attaching the event handler should be wrapped in a DOM ready handler, or be included at the bottom of the page. This ensures that the target `form` exists in the page, otherwise the event handler will not be attached to the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**:

By adding `e.preventDefault();`

Example:

```
$('.chat_form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //ajax code here
});
```

**Solution 2**

Alternatively, by adding little javascript `onsubmit="return false"` code in form tag:

Example:

```
<form class="chat_form" method="post" id="chat_form" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return false">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have propagation of the event by default, you probably need one or both of these calls:

```
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
```

When the `submit()` is called on your object, it won't stop there. It will call the default afterward, so you want to add a parameter and then do those calls as in:

```
$('.chat_form').submit(function(e){  // <- add parameter here

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $.ajax({
        url: "runMe.cfm",
        type: "POST",
        data: $('.chat_form').serialize(),    
        success: function() {
            $('.chat_form input').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `e.preventDefault()` for can submit the form only from the javascript code.

```
$('.chat_form').submit(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url: "runMe.cfm",
        type: "POST",
        data: $('.chat_form').serialize(),    
        success: function() {
            $('.chat_form input').val('');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault() // put that line of code here or on last line on success function
});
```